# Libraries work fine in Spyder but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, spyder

I have a couple libraries that run fine in Spyder but not in PyCharm.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

In PyCharm, I thought I could click File > Settings and point the Project Interpreter to Python 3.6, which is what I'm using for Spyder, and that works fine.  Is there some other setting that needs to be re-pointed?  Or, is there something else that I'm missing?  Finally, if I ned a new library, I go to the 'Anaconda Prompt' and 'pip install ...' the necessary library.  Will this be the same for PyCharm?  I recently installed PyCharm and I'm trying to understand it better.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand clearly, changing the interpreter in pycharm solved the issue?

Comment: No, changing the interpreter did NOT solve the issue.  I thought that's all I had  to do, but apparently there is something more to this.

Comment: I am not familiar with sns, but what is the problem with plt? you might need to configure the backend.

Comment: Also - Spyder usualy use the interperter in the conda env, which is not necissarly the same as what 'Python 3.6' will be in the interperter choosing in pycharm. Make sure you manualy navigate to the right folder and pick the right interperter. the path can be checked from within spyder by print(sys.executable)

Comment: Thanks Or Dinari!!  That was it!!!

Comment: Cheers, posting this as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spyder (When used thru anaconda) will usually use either the default anaconda bin, such as `/home/user/anaconda2/bin/python`, or when working from an env, `/home/user/anaconda2/envs/python3/bin/python`. 
 
This is not necessarily the same python as your OS path points to. When configuring pycharm to work with anaconda, you must explicitly point to the path of the wanted interpreter.

Checking the path for your interpreter executable from spyder can be done by:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

When setting the right interpreter all your modification to the conda env will be working with pycharm.