# PyCharm can't find module which is installed

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

I'm trying to use numpy in PyCharm, in Spyder it does work, but with PyCharm I have troubles.

```
import numpy

a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]

numpy.savetxt("geht das jetzt.txt", a)
```

PyCharm suggests numpy, but when I try to run the code I get the following Error:

```
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.
Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I did already try this: [Libraries work fine in Spyder but not in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249206/libraries-work-fine-in-spyder-but-not-in-pycharm) but without success.

Comment: Go to `File > Settings > Project > Project interpreter`. There you should see a list of all the packages installed in the environment you work in. Can you see `Numpy` in this list? If yes, please indicate the version of Numpy as well as the version of Python you use. It is difficult to help without this info.

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried this, it didn't work. Allthought I don't really understand what the problem was, I found a solution. Installing Numpy again (using pip and not pycharm or conda) did work.

Comment: There must have been a mismatch between the interpreters as hinted to by @Eskapp.

Answer (score 0):

Allthought I don't really understand what the problem was, I found a solution. Installing Numpy again (using pip and not pycharm or conda) did work.